# How to update the foreign key of a table created from N to N relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

What happens is that a change a service (`Servicio`) of a technical (`Tecnico`) to other technical. I need update that change in the table call `Servicio_Tecnico`. I don't how to do it

**Tecnico Model**

```
class Tecnico extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Tecnico';
protected $primaryKey = 'idTecnico';
protected $hidden = array('Contrasena');
protected $fillable = array(
                            'idTecnico',
                            'Nombre',
                            'Apellido',
                            'Telefono',
                            'Contrasena',
                            'Foto',
                            );
public function servicios(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Servicio', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'Tecnico_idTecnico', 'Servicio_idServicio');
}
}
```

**Servicio Model**

```
class Servicio extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Servicio';
protected $primaryKey = 'idServicio';
protected $fillable = array(
                            'Direccion',
                            'RutaPDF',
                            'Completado',
                            'TipoUsuario',
                            'Zonal',
                            'RutaCliente',
                            'Prima'
                            );
public function tecnicos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tecnico', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'Servicio_idServicio', 'Tecnico_idTecnico');
}
public function materialUsado(){
    return $this->hasMany('MaterialUsado', 'Servicio_idServicio');
}
}
```

This is my code when I try to change

```
    $idTecnico_old = Input::get('idTecnicoViejo');
    $idTecnico_new = Input::get('idTecnico');
    $idServicio = Input::get('idServicio');
    if($idTecnico_new != ''){

        $servicio = Servicio::find($idServicio);
        $tecnico = $servicio->tecnicos()->get();
        $tecnico = $tecnico->find($idTecnico_old);
        $tecnico->pivot->Tecnico_idTecnico = $idTecnico_new;
        $tecnico->pivot->save;

    }
```

help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use sync instead of save for your pivot table.

```
$servicio = Servicio::find($idServicio);
$servicio->tecnicos()->sync(array('Tecnico_idTecnico' => $idTecnico_new));    
$servicio->update();
```

Comment: thank you, I make a little change ``$servicio->tecnicos()->sync(array('Tecnico_idTecnico' => $idTecnico_new));``